# Determine the provider of an email address

Tags: email, oauth, gmail, outlook.com

I'm trying to implement a "Sign Up" function for my website that allows people to sign up with their enterprise credentials.

I would love for it to be as easy as a textbox that they type their email address into without having to select a provider like "Outlook.com" or "Gmail" or "Salesforce"

Is there a way to *sniff* out the email provider by the address?

PSEUDO

`bool isOutlook = outlookapi.doesaddressexist("joe@ibm.com")`

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to extract the domain name you can use regex and a formula field:

```
"\\@.*" // returns e.g. @ibm.com
```

**EDIT**

Another option is to use pattern matching in apex. In a second step create a new sObject called "Provider-Domain" add a Text field called "domain". Create an entry for each provider and build a new SOQL query like:

```
[SELECT Name FROM Provider_Domain__c WHERE Domian__c = :YOUR_EXTRACTED_DOMAIN]
```

Comment: I appreciate the response, but that wasn't the question. The domain != the provider. IBM.COM could be a mail address from many providers.